# Best option for marshaling native arrays using SAFEARRAY

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, marshalling, safearray

I'd like to produce some data in C++ in the form of array of doubles, and then pass it to other clients that can be written in other languages like C#, or possibly even JavaScript.

What marshaling option would you use for the array of doubles?

1. A `SAFEARRAY` of doubles
2. A `SAFEARRAY` of `VARIANT`s that store doubles
3. A `VARIANT` holding a `SAFEARRAY` of `VARIANT`s that store doubles

What are there pros and cons (if any) for these options?

Comment: Typically, when dealing with interop, JavaScript expects objects and arrays to be wrapped in `VARIANT`, so you cant go wrong with #3 if you can live with the overhead. You might be able to use #1 stored in a `VARIANT`, depending on your JavaScript engine's level of `SAFEARRAY` type support.

Comment: @RemyLebeau If you rewrite your comment as answer, I'd be happy to up vote it.